# docker daemon exec: "dockerd" : executable not found in %PATH%

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I'm trying to run this command :

```
docker daemon --insecure-registry 192.168.99.100:5000
```

but i'm gettin ghe following error:

> exec: "dockerd": executable file not found in %PATH%

I'm using win7 and docker-toolbox 1.12.2 with VM Virtual Box.

What is the problem here? 
there is a way to run this  command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is indeed what [issue 27102](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/27102) report:

> Docker Daemon command `dockerd` not found on latest stable Docker for Mac and Docker Toolbox

(this is for mac but also applies on Windows)

> Docker for Mac should probably print a different message, also, we may need to check if the CLI is on the same "host" as the daemon, and print a different message based on that (as running dockerd wont work if the daemon is on a remote server).
>
> the daemon runs in a Linux virtual machine, so you do not need to (and cannot) run it manually. It is already running of the whale is in the top bar.

[Conclusion](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/27102#issuecomment-908280713): (Aug. 2021):

> I'm closing this ticket, because the current behaviour is as expected.
>
> I think this was originally opened when the docker cli still had a daemon subcommand (during the transition from a single binary to separate binaries for the cli and daemon), which is no longer the case.
>
> The `dockerd` binary, which is the docker daemon, is not available for macOS (and unlikely will be), because it's a Linux binary that (on Docker Desktop for Mac) runs inside the Docker Desktop VM.

---

[In 2022](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/27102#issuecomment-1088782126):

> I'm having this exact same issue on the most recent MacOs version (Monterey, Version 12.3.1 (21E258)).
>
> I've uninstalled Docker & reinstalled several times, if I run `docker ps` or `docker run hello-world` as [paulinechi describes](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/27102#issuecomment-908171706), I get that same error:
>
> ```
> docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at `tcp://35.215.110.128:2375`. 
> Is the docker daemon running?...
> ```
>
> Answer:
>
> **Make sure you don't have a `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable set**; from that error, it looks like either you have a `DOCKER_HOST` env-var, or possibly a docker context that defines a non-standard location to connect to the daemon.
>
> The default should be to connect with the Engine API using a unix-socket (`unix:///var/run/docker.sock`)
>
> Confirmation:
>
> I forgot I was pointing to a `DOCKER_HOST` on a remote machine that has since shut down.

---

Nov 2023:

> I'm under macos Silicon M2 and the question is simple:
> Is it possible to run the `dockerd` command under macOS without it returning: "`command not found: dockerd`" ?

The answer is clear, by [Sebastiaan van Stijn (`thaJeztah`), Principal Software Engineer @Docker](https://github.com/thaJeztah):

> Not directly possible; Linux containers require a Linux kernel, so on macOS, the actual containers (and the `dockerd` daemon) runs inside a VM, not on the macOS host.
>
> (We have considered experimenting with a "fake" `dockerd` that could act as a proxy to control/configure the daemon inside the VM, but that was more of a "fun exercise").

Comment: thanks, there is a workaround to run this command in this version?

Comment: @yuvalsimhon I suspect what the issue is saying is that the error message is confusing and that `dockerd` should not be called.

Comment: I'm not running the `dockerd` mans that also `docker daemon` cannot be called?

Comment: @yuvalsimhon yes, docker daemon should already be running in a VM, not called directly. You might need to change the configuration used by the VM in order to start docker daemon. https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/83#issuecomment-130803948

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I'm able to pull&push from docker. but i'm trying to pull from kubectl (Minikube) but getting SSL Tunnel error, but this is a different issue.