# how to connect to Docker via TCP on MacOS

Tags: macos, docker, tcp, docker-for-mac

I am a neophyte when it comes to networking issues more generally, and Docker specifically, which I'm sure will become apparent in this question.

Right now the relatively simple thing I'd like to accomplish is enabling the tcp socket on Docker for Mac (and further to that, understanding where to ping my Docker host from a client machine).  I'm cheating a little bit in that I'm not describing my ultimate goal, and I know that causes the X-Y problem, but my real goal right now is to understand both Docker and networking a little better, and if I can get to the point where I had the tcp socket enabled I'll have learned something.

Here are the obstacles:  [This](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#examples) is the main documentation about enabling the tcp socket for the docker daemon.  But apparently this dockerd binary [does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41662287/docker-daemon-exec-dockerd-executable-not-found-in-path) on Docker for Mac.

So how do I accomplish the analogous task?  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39411126/access-docker-daemon-remote-api-on-docker-for-mac) suggests one possibility, but one problem I have is that I don't understand what IP my docker host is at with that option (this is probably because I'm confused about networking issues).

Also, if you click the whale, there's a daemon tab that takes a JSON object.  Maybe I could put the port and IP address at which I would like to listen there? But using what syntax? What is the name of the key?  Where is this documented? If the answer is [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/) I don't understand it.

Any help you could provide is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See below github issue

https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1443#issuecomment-288055240

which points to

https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1156#issuecomment-273764881

and which indicates you can't do it as of now using config. You can do it like below

```
$ socat TCP-LISTEN:2376,reuseaddr,fork,bind=127.0.0.1 UNIX-CLIENT:/var/run/docker.sock
```

This will expose the docker socket on `2376` on your mac